# Absolutely positioned div goes outside the borders of the parent

Tags: html, css

The `#third` circle (with letter `C`) has `top: 0` and should be located like this:

[image]

but is instead located like this:

[image]

JSFiddle: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/MWqxpzr

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 2em;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 80%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#outside {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: green;
}

#body-wrapper {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.circle {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 20em;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

#first {
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
}

#second {
  left: 80px;
  top: 20%;
}

#third {
  left: 30%;
  top: 0%;
}

#fourth {
  left: 40%;
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id='body-wrapper'>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='circle' id='first'>A</div>
    <div class='circle' id='second'>B</div>
    <div class='circle' id='third'>C</div>
    <div class='circle' id='fourth'>D</div>
  </div>
  <div id='outside'>
    Outside text
  </div>
</div>
```

Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: they are not absolute, but relative

Comment: I don't see any absolute positioning in your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a guess at what you want, set the wrapper's position to `relative` and the inner elements' position to `absolute`. Simply putting a top position on an element doesn't make it absolutely positioned.

You'll probably need to adjust X-axis position values to get back to where things were.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 2em;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 80%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  position: relative;
}

#outside {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: green;
}

#body-wrapper {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.circle {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 20em;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
}

#first {
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
}

#second {
  left: 80px;
  top: 20%;
}

#third {
  left: 30%;
  top: 0%;
}

#fourth {
  left: 40%;
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id='body-wrapper'>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='circle' id='first'>A</div>
    <div class='circle' id='second'>B</div>
    <div class='circle' id='third'>C</div>
    <div class='circle' id='fourth'>D</div>
  </div>
  <div id='outside'>
    Outside text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. So the `absolute` on circles would only work if the parent div has a `relative` position?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values - It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the padding of the circle class (1em), is overlapping the top setting. Same for the 1px of border. Try accounting for this extra space by using something like:

```
top: calc(0% + 1em + 1px);
```

This will bring the circle in line with the edge of the blue div.

However, if I understand what you're trying to do properly, this should apply to all other circles and not just the 3rd, as they all have the same starting point.

Comment: But how can padding me a culprit here, if padding only affects space within a circle (red)?

Comment: In contrast to the other answer, mine does not alter the rest of your code. The way you had everything set up (relative circle classes), the top setting actually started counting from the top of the whole viewport. Not the parent element. In this case, all extra space matters. Try my simple solution and you will see it works. Not saying the other answer is wrong, but the way you only asked why and how do I fix it, I thought i'd do it in the easiest way possible without altering much of your original code.